# My xampp "http://localhost/" wordpress site address points to outside domain

Tags: php, wordpress, https, xampp

I downloaded my organization's wordpress website to work on a test copy on my local machine (xampp) web server, but when I go to the address http://localhost/ it takes me to the actual live website (https://brightwaterfoundation.org) rather than the one on my machine.... any idea why this is happening?

Comment: it must be diverted in windows hosts file

Comment: Tried that.... didn't seem to do anything.  Still goes to the outside domain when I type in http://localhost

http://image.prntscr.com/image/1a1f23d41f4c44a981690dd79b3c9ecd.png

Comment: You need to add something to wp-config.php file. The reason for the redirect is because it is expecting you to be attempting to go to that domain. Basically like a .htaccess rewrite. I will attempt to find what you have to change on the internet.

Comment: You would have to find these two things: 

`define('WP_HOME','http://example.com');
define('WP_SITEURL','http://example.com');`

Comment: have you changed the siteurl and home in your wp_options tabe in database,
also check htaccess file

Comment: @ashanrupasinghe +1 for wp_options table. I did not even know that was a thing.

Comment: I changed those two.  That did the trick!  Thanks @ashanrupasinghe and @McStuffins!  You're both awesome!